# Error possibly from using which within a function, or not specifying variables in function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm receiving an error when I try to run my function, and I think it could be related to either the fact that I'm including quotes around words in the function after its been developed, or that I'm subsetting in a way that is not ok for R. At the bottom of the code chunk, I run two lines that give me what I want, but without relying on a function. Using a function would definitely save a lot of time, so any suggestions for handling the error(s) here would be appreciated immensely. My function ideally will give the results of several t-tests.

Example code below

```
# Develop dataframe
example <- data.frame(
  c(rep(25, 25), rep(50,25), rep(75,25), rep(100,25)),
  c(rep(c("vaccine1", "vaccine2", "vaccine3", "vaccine4"), 25)),
  c(rep(rnorm(5), 20))
)
colnames(example) <- c("day", "treatment", "allout")

# Generate function
myfunction <- function(dataset, outcome, treatvar, treat1, treat2){
  cutdataset <- with(dataset, dataset[ (treatment==treat1 | treatment==treat2), ])
  ttests <- c(
    round(as.numeric(t.test(outcome~treatvar, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==25),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
    round(as.numeric(t.test(outcome~treatvar, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==50),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
    round(as.numeric(t.test(outcome~treatvar, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==75),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
    round(as.numeric(t.test(outcome~treatvar, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==99),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
    round(as.numeric(t.test(outcome~treatvar, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==100),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
    round(as.numeric(t.test(outcome~treatvar, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==125),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
    round(as.numeric(t.test(outcome~treatvar, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==150),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3)
  )
  print(ttests)
}

# Run function
myfunction("example", "allout", "treatment", "vaccine1", "vaccine3")

# Isolated cases
cutdataset <- with(example, example[ (treatment=="vaccine1" | treatment=="vaccine3"), ])
round(as.numeric(t.test(allout~treatment, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==25),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3)
```

EDIT: I actually realized that (a) a more flexible version of `myfunction` would have `cutdataset` be able to take `treatvar` rather than `treatment`, the latter of which is actually a variable in the dataset, when I think it would be ideal to specify via `treatvar`. So I slipped that in `cutdataset` but I don't think its working well. I am also (b) having trouble incorporating another loop that I thought would not be problematic (and so I did not include it previously, just wanting to focus on the t-tests), but turned out being an issue, and again I think this is related to strings and such. I.e. I just get a column of zeros for the column n1. Any help would be appreciated, and any tips on why this is happening would really help me to avoid this in the future. I am incorporating the info so far provided by Ben.

```
# Develop dataframe
example <- data.frame(
  c(rep(25, 25), rep(50,25), rep(75,25), rep(100,25)),
  c(rep(c("vaccine1", "vaccine2", "vaccine3", "vaccine4"), 25)),
  c(rep(rnorm(5), 20))
)
colnames(example) <- c("day", "treatment", "allout")

# Generate function
myfunction <- function(dataset, outcome, treatvar, treat1, treat2){
  n1 <- c(
    nrow(dataset[dataset$day == 25 & dataset$treatvar == treat1,]),
    nrow(dataset[dataset$day == 50 & dataset$treatvar == treat1,]),
    nrow(dataset[dataset$day == 75 & dataset$treatvar == treat1,]),
    nrow(dataset[dataset$day == 100 & dataset$treatvar == treat1,])
  )
  cutdataset <- with(dataset, dataset[ (treatvar==treat1 | treatvar==treat2), ])
  frmla <- reformulate(termlabels = treatvar, response = outcome)
  ttests <- sapply(c(25,50,75,100), function(x) 
    round(as.numeric(t.test(frmla, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==x),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3))
  print(cbind(n1, ttests))
}

# Run function
myfunction(example, "allout", "treatment", "vaccine1", "vaccine3")

# Isolated cases
cutdataset <- with(example, example[ (treatment=="vaccine1" | treatment=="vaccine3"), ])
round(as.numeric(t.test(allout~treatment, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==25),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3)
nrow(example[example$day == 25 & example$treatment == "vaccine1",])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use either `as.formula` or `reformulate` to build your formula from strings. Then you can plug in your formula in the `t.test` directly.

You want to remove quotes from `example` (your data frame name). It looks like your intention was to pass in the actual dataframe in creating `cutdataset` from it.

In addition, you could use `sapply` or other method instead of repeating your very similar statements for `t.test`. But either way should give similar results.

```
# Generate function
myfunction <- function(dataset, outcome, treatvar, treat1, treat2){
  cutdataset <- with(dataset, dataset[ (treatment==treat1 | treatment==treat2), ])
  frmla <- reformulate(termlabels = treatvar, response = outcome)
  # ttests <- c(
  #   round(as.numeric(t.test(frmla, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==25),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
  #   round(as.numeric(t.test(frmla, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==50),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
  #   round(as.numeric(t.test(frmla, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==75),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3),
  #   round(as.numeric(t.test(frmla, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==100),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3)
  # )
  ttests <- sapply(c(25,50,75,100), function(x) 
    round(as.numeric(t.test(frmla, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==x),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3))
  print(ttests)
}

# Run function
myfunction(example, "allout", "treatment", "vaccine1", "vaccine3")
```

**Output**

```
[1] -0.065  0.366  0.065 -0.366
```

**Edit (2/29/20)**:

You can still pass in the string name of the treatment variable, and extract the column data from your dataset. This is likely preferable to trying to pass in both a dataset and a column separately from the same dataset. To extract the column data of `treatment` you can do `dataset[[treatvar]]`.

In addition, you can also calculate rows of data for `n1` within your `sapply` to simplify. See if this works for you:

```
# Generate function
myfunction <- function(dataset, outcome, treatvar, treat1, treat2){
  cutdataset <- dataset[dataset[[treatvar]]==treat1 | dataset[[treatvar]]==treat2, ]
  frmla <- reformulate(termlabels = treatvar, response = outcome)
  ttests <- sapply(c(25,50,75,100), function(x) {
    c(n1 = nrow(dataset[dataset$day==x & dataset[[treatvar]] == treat1,]),
      ttest = round(as.numeric(t.test(frmla, data = cutdataset[which(cutdataset$day==x),], var.equal = TRUE)[1]),3))
  })
  print(t(ttests))
}

# Run function
myfunction(example, "allout", "treatment", "vaccine1", "vaccine3")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. And for the use of sapply() as well. Thanks Ben!

Comment: Actually, I think I realized that there was a component that was making the above code "easier" - i.e., I think I would like cutdataset to be able to take treatvar rather than treatment. Also, there's some other function that I use in my function that wasn't included that doesn't work nicely. Hoping I can get some feedback!

Comment: @rpickmans see edited answer above. Hope this works out for you.